# VirtualHost by different domains (nginx)

Tags: nginx, domain, port

I have two HTTP servers. One of them (A) is listening to port 3000 and the other one (B) is listening to port 4000. Also, I have two domains `example1.com` and `example2.com`. In the other hand, I have nginx server listening at port 80.

I would like to get responses from server A when the request is using `example1.com` domain and responses from server B when the request is using `example2.com`.

How should I configure nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `proxy_pass` (which may require more configuration that this)

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass

```
http {
  server {
    server_name www.example1.com;

    root /var/www/example1.com/htdocs;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
      // more configuration
    }
  }

  server {
    server_name www.example2.com;

    root /var/www/example2.com/htdocs;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
      // more configuration
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup vhost & alias for example1.com & exmaple2.com

## cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/

create an virtual host for your domain for more detail follow this link.
http://wiki.nginx.org/VirtualHostExample

```
http {
  index index.html;
 
  server {
    server_name www.example1.com;
    access_log logs/example2.access.log main;
 
    root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;
  }
 
  server {
    server_name www.exampl2.com;
    access_log  logs/example2.access.log main;
 
    root /var/www/example2.com/htdocs;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, I have my own servers listening in 3000 and 4000.